# Why shared data of Angular Service is not being updated in the html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, components, share

I'm using a service to share an array between 02 unrelated components, "home" and "results". In my `interaction.service.ts` I have this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class InteractionService {

  private _teacherMessageSource = new Subject<any>();
  teacherMessage$ = this._teacherMessageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  sendMessage(message: any){
    this._teacherMessageSource.next(message)
  }
}
```

"message" is an array of floats but I just set it to any. When i get a response from the backend in the "home" component, I just pass it to the sendMessage() function of the Servic:

```
this.http.post<any>("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", formData).subscribe(
      (response)=> {   
        
        console.log(response)  // array of floats   
        this._interationService.sendMessage(response);   

      },
      (error)=> console.log(error)
    )
```

Then in the result component I get the message and I can print it on the console, but when I affect it to another array "selectedMessage" in order to print it in the HTML, it always shows null:

```
  public selectedMessage=[];

  constructor(public _interactionService: InteractionService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSpecialities();
    this._interactionService.teacherMessage$
      .subscribe(
          message => { 
            alert(message); // message is an array of floats and it shows normally with alert(message)
            this.selectedMessage = message;
            //console.log(this.selectedMessage);
 
          }
      );
  }
```

My html is:

```
<ul>
  <li><strong> SSI </strong>: {{selectedMessage[0]}}</li>
  <li> <strong>RSD</strong>:{{selectedMessage[1]}}  </li>
  <li><strong>IL</strong>: {{selectedMessage[2]}}</li>
  <li><strong>MIV</strong>:  {{selectedMessage[3]}}</li>
  <li><strong>SSI</strong>: {{selectedMessage[4]}}</li>
  <li><strong>BIGDATAA</strong>: {{selectedMessage[5]}}</li>
  <li><strong>BIOINFO</strong>: {{selectedMessage[6]}} </li>
</ul>
```

[image]
but nothing shows up in the page:

What could be the problem please?

Comment: instantiate `_teacherMessageSource` with `new BehaviorSubject<any>(null)` does it work then ?

Comment: oh it kinda worked!! I don't know why i'm getting all the elements of the array in the selectedMessage[0] tho, the others are empty

Comment: that's just data model change. you're not getting what you think you're getting from the API. adjust accordingly. the real issue is the late subscription (you subscribe AFTER data arrived). this is why using behavior subject solves it.

Comment: @Stavm THANK YOU so much, i managed to fix it. I really appreciate it thanks.  you can  answer the question so i can accept it if you want!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your html is rendering sync data, while in component you provide async data (even in ngOnInit).
Easy workaround would be put *ngIf in your list and better declare selectedMessage as proper array, but not assigning it as empty array:

```
selectedMessage: selectedMessage[];

<ul *ngIf=selectedMessage>
  <li><strong> SSI </strong>: {{selectedMessage[0]}}</li>
  <li> <strong>RSD</strong>:{{selectedMessage[1]}}  </li>
  <li><strong>IL</strong>: {{selectedMessage[2]}}</li>
  <li><strong>MIV</strong>:  {{selectedMessage[3]}}</li>
  <li><strong>SSI</strong>: {{selectedMessage[4]}}</li>
  <li><strong>BIGDATAA</strong>: {{selectedMessage[5]}}</li>
  <li><strong>BIOINFO</strong>: {{selectedMessage[6]}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still it shows the same page without the values :/ but when I print it in the console in the when subscribing  i get a result..

Comment: @Mounir you mean you can log //console.log(this.selectedMessage); or //console.log(message);

Comment: both give the same result, the expected array

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an async data that may not be there. The straight forward solution would be the async pipe.

```js
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let msg of (interactionService.teacherMessage$ | async)">
    <strong> Something </strong>: {{msg}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

- This avoids access to empty array
- Link to a sample code on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12ziph?file=src/app/app.component.html